# Which Eclipse version is compatible with Tomcat 10, or do I go back to Tomcat 9?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm starting a web development project with a new install of Eclipse for Web developers; I installed Eclipse 2020-06 and Tomcat 10. But evidently those are not compatible; the first example JSP I entered has an error saying that HTTPServlet is not on the path.

On looking further, I discovered that the servlet library pathnames have changed; used to be javax... and are now jakarta... I'm assuming that's the problem, though I don't have definite confirmation of that.

Should I be using a newer version of eclipse, or an older version of Tomcat? Or is there something else I should be using?

EDIT: also using Java 11.0

EDIT: version of eclipse was a typo -- 2022-06 is the actual version.

Comment: you should also add the jdk version that you are using...

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of that. 11.0.

Comment: though the jdk version has nothing to do with the solution, specifying it is a good practice while asking questions..

Comment: Why install an old version of Eclipse?

Comment: Tomcat 10.0 was released a good 6 months after Eclipse 2020-06, which is now 2 years and 8 releases behind. You need a newer Eclipse release, like the current one: 2022-06. Whether you want to use Tomcat 9 or 10 is really up to you, and you haven't said why you should pick one over the other.

Comment: Sorry, all -- the version of eclipse was a typo -- 2022-06 is the actual version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you are assuming right...
There is a breaking change in package name for tomcat 9 to tomcat 10 from javax.* to jakarta.* respectively....

To make your project to work,

Option 1 : You downgrade to tomcat Version that uses the package (javax).... For Eg. Tomcat 9

Option 2 : You Make changes in your codebase and change the package name to use jakarta and keep using tomcat 10 or above...

Comment: Yeah, except that I cannot change the package name -- I'm not sure where the package name is in the JSP support, but I'm certain I cannot change it. I imagine there's a JSP support package, possibly used in eclipse 2022-12, that does use the newer package name, but that seems to be a pre-stable release (not sure) and I was hoping for advice on whether going that way was better than downgrading Tomcat.

Comment: Not really a “downgrade” when switching from Tomcat 10.0 to Tomcat 9. They are equivalent products, with the only significant difference being the `jakarta.*` name change.

Comment: @arcy You’ll need to change the versions of related API, such as Servlet and JSP to match the version expected by Tomcat. See the [*Which version?*](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page on the Tomcat site.

Comment: There is no 2022-12 release or pre-release, yet, but 2022-06 will work with both releases of Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Update to Eclipse 2022-06. It works with both versions, largely automatically.

Comment: The 2020-06 was a typo; I am using 2022-06, and it is not working with 10 automatically. I switched to Tomcat 9.

Comment: @arcy What was the actual error message you were getting?